# Partially select the text of a DataGridView cell when clicked

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to programmatically select a specific portion of the text of a DataGridView cell whenever a user enters it?
For example, if a user enters a cell and types **`hello world`** in it and then re-enters the same cell, the substring **`world`** will be automatically selected, (i.e. without user action).

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, using the [EditingControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing) event. The **`e.Control`** member of the [DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridvieweditingcontrolshowingeventargs), references the Edit Control of the current cell.
After having checked whether the Edit Control is of type [DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxeditingcontrol), `e.Control` is cast to a [TextBoxBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.select?) class, which provides the [Select()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.select?) method used to select the cell's Text.

I introduced a short delay before selecting part of the Text, because the event is raised before the cell is invalidated. If the selection is performed right away, the Edit Control will re-select all the Text after the cell is invalidated and the previous selection is lost.

This method selects the last word of the text or all the text if there's only one word. Can be easily adapted to select any other section of the text.

Sample functionality:

[image: DataGridView EditingControlShowing]

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl tbec)
    {
        var cellText = tbec.Text;
        if (cellText?.Length > 1)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                string word = cellText.Split().Last();
                tbec.Select(cellText.Length - word.Length, word.Length);
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the delay, if you do it using `BeginInvoke`. Something like `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { }));`.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei  Thanks. That's actually really better :). Updated.

Comment: Thanks you so much. This was really helpful.