# Determine initial text selection in DataGridView Cell

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

A little question on use of DataGridView.

When I enter a Cell, text is all selected (in blue in the example). But I want to set the caret position at the right side of the text, for my user can delete the last character without clicking twice to place caret.

Have you some idea, because I don't find the good property...

I try to change behaviour when I enter in cell (edit with F2, in simple click), but test is always all select

Comment: [Partially select the text of a DataGridView cell when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54777466/7444103) -- Of course, instead of selecting part of the text, you can set `SelectionStart` at the end of the text (`SelectionLength` remains `0`)

Comment: Thanks for you help, is a good exemple ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use DataGridView1.CellClick event and BeginEdit to allow casting Cell in textbox. After that set cursor position using textbox.select (from,Length) :

```
Private Sub cellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    DataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)
    Dim tbCell As TextBox = CType(DataGridView1.EditingControl, TextBox)
    tbCell.Select(tbCell.Text.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks tuyau2poil, is exactly what I search. You're a chief

Answer (score 0):

The functioning of DataGridView has always been a problem for me.

tuyau2poil, your answer was perfect for my first question. I integred the code in DataGridView_CellDoubleClick and it's OK. Thousand of thanks

For my second question, I think the way is on Jimy anwser:

Now I search, when I select the cell with 1 click and press "Del", to delete the last character. That works, but when I type a new character + Enter, that delete all the cell for write only the new charactere.

This is for my users have to modify only the last number of the serial number enter in cell...

"21000_001" to become "21000_002" with "Del" + key press "2" + Enter .
Actually I've got "21000_001" then "2"

I think solution is arount of DataGridView_EditingControlShowing

Thanks

Comment: You're asking a question in an answer. You should create a new thread if you have more questions or use the comments section of the answers that have been provided.